# Can we scrape linkdin/ jobs using scrapy? i was looking for tutorial on it but failed to find any?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

can we scrape linkdin/ jobs  using scrapy? i was looking for tutorial on it but failed to find any?
i search on github aswell but could'nt find any related repository.

can anyone tell me the reason? or can provide a simple spider of scrapy so that i can use and  modify that . but using **SCRAPY** only

Answer (score 2):

You can't scrape linkedin/ jobs using scrapy only because scrapy can't render `JavaScript` but can scrape linkedin/ jobs using `scrapy-seleniumRequest` because Linkedin completely depends on JavaScript.

scrapy-selenium documentation is [here](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-selenium/)

Comment: Isn't there any possibility to scrape some API endpoints on Linkedin?

Comment: No, they didn't use API endpoint. Everything is controlled dynamically by JS.

Comment: waht about scrapy-splash? isn't it a good option?

Comment: I recomand you not to use spalsh because no one is   taking care to maintain it

Comment: I am not familiar with scrapy-selenium , so I was trying to scrape this using splash but I am unable to locate the next-page url can you help me finding next page url ?  I will definetly try to do with scrapy-selenium but for time being i want to do it with scrapy-splash